# Check sum calculation

Tags: checksum, error-detection

I am new to know about check sum. So kindly help me.

I have these four binary values and i need to calculate the check sum for these numbers.
They are

```
0111011101100
1011011000110
0011011011110
1011010110010
```

I really don't know the algorithm to calculate these values. Can somebody shed a light on this. Whats the final checksum for these four values.

Comment: "I really don't know the algorithm to calculate these values". That's a problem, because there are a number of checksum algorithms to choose from, and they all yield different results.

Comment: A checksum is the result of a specific algorithm; however, they are many different checksum algorithms; you need to check *which* algorithm your specification says to use, or dream one up.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "the checksum". There are many algorithms for "checksum" calculation. CRC32, Adler32, in a certain way as well MD4, MD5, SHA1, other SHA algorithms, etc.